# Javascript event when page is displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, kendo-ui

I have a web page with some divs and content (Kendo UI grid inside of Kendo Splitter) that get automatically sized to fit the available space when the page is ready or resized. This happens via Javascript+JQuery common triggers handling and it's working smoothly.

But when a toolbar is open, like Firebug, the following happens:

If I refresh the and switch to another browser's tab before the page is loaded, then I come back to my page, I see that one of divs(grid's one) it's bigger than its container, so it overflows of few pixels. By the way it happens a few instants after the page has been displayed, so no `visibilitychange` trigger can be used.

The same happens in IE by simply opening the in-page debugger.

I don't think that KendoUI widget's are related to this problem, but i report it for sake of completeness.

<del>So i thought that the best way to fix it, would be to take advantage of some event that triggers when the document is displayed by the user. **Does it exist?**</del>

Answer (score 2):

You might want to listen for `focus` and `blur` events on `window` like this:

```
$(window).on('focus', function() {
    //(...)
});
```

`blur` event is fired when you go to another tab or to another window than browser window. `focus` event does the opposite.
I could add an jsfiddle here but it uses `iframes` so it couldn't be properly tested.

Comment: I tried but as i state in the question, it's doesn't work because i've noticed that the resize mess happens a short after i switch back to the page. I think the only solution would be setting a timeout..